# Displaying smallest and largest input

Tags: python

I need to write a program that prompts the user to enter numbers, and stores/displays the largest & smallest integer entered.

However, I can only do this with simple data types (no arrays.)

This is what I have so far.

```
def main()

while number != -99:
    number = input('Enter a number: ')
    compare = input('Please enter another number: ')
        if compare < number then
            compare = smallest
```

I'm sorry it's just a mess. We're not actually taught python in this class, only psuedo-code then just kind of sent on our own to figure it out.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have any ideas about how to do this?  We'd be happy to help, but you need to demonstrate a basic effort to solve the problem and provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to keep all the numbers, then simply keep two variables maximum and minimum in two variables and only assign the latest user data entry to one or the other depending on whether it is lesser / greater or not - plus a special case to get the first number started in both variables. Here is a little pseudo-code example...

```
Maximum = NULL
Minimum = NULL
Do 
  Get User Input string
  If Input is Blank Then Exit Loop
  Input = Convert Input to Number
  If Maximum=NULL 
     Then Maximum=Input
     Else If Input > Maximum Then Input = Maximum
  If Minimum=NULL 
     Then Minimum=Input
     Else If Input < Minimum Then Input = Minimum
Loop
Print "Min = " + Minimum
Print "Max = " + Maximum
```